# How to setup routes when you have an API and a website

Tags: laravel, api, routes

Let's assume I have a Laravel application where I have a page where I display all my customers in a table. So in my `web.php` I point `/customers` to the `index` method in my `CustomersController`. The `index` method gets all the customer objects and returns them and the index blade in a view.

Now I also would like to build an api using the `api.php` routes where I can get all my customers with a request. But if I point `/customers` to the `index` method in my `api.php` routes it would return a view and not all the customer objects. Which would be useless.

So my question is what the best way and most efficient way is to handle this problem. Because creating a "duplicate" CustomerController just for the api requests seems a little too excesive.

Comment: In your controller, you can conditional return a view or, by example, a json  response. Ie: `if ($request->expectsJson()) {
    // ...
}`. Look here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#content-negotiation

Comment: This works like a charm. If you can post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: By default laravel has web.php routes and api.php routes where the routes will be placed at api/*. Making if conditions on all routes is tedius and violates single responsibility principle

Comment: But that is the whole point. In my api.php file I want to point to the exact same controller methods. When the request comes from the web routes it points to the index method and returns all the objects in a view. While in the api routes it will point to the exact method in the controller but will return only the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a condition in the index method

for example:

```
public function index(Request $request){
 if($request->is("api*"){
   return response($customers);
 }
 $data['customers'] = $customers;
 return view("customers blade")->with($data);
}
```

Comment: I want to state that for me this solution works better then using $request->expectsJson(). Because I noticed that when using a service like cloudflare that for some reason the Accept header in the ajax request gets changed by cloudflare and the expectsJson() doesn't work anymore. Since Laravel determines the expected result by checking the Accept header.